# How do I apply column styling at the grid level with Kendo Grid for Angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, styling

I'm working on an Angular 11 application with the Kendo Grid for Angular. I'm wondering how to apply a border to the columns globally (i.e. at the level of the grid itself). I'm not finding anything. I know I can apply a border to each column individually like this:

```
<kendo-grid-column ... [headerStyle]="{'border-color': '#000'}">
...
</kendo-grid-column>
```

That gives me this:

[image]

But how do I bring it up to the level of the grid itself so that I just have to code it once and it gets applied to all columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need set styles globally then you have two ways:

1. set style into styles.scss

   .k-grid-header .k-header {
   border-right: 1px solid black;
   }
2. find a theme of kendo and override styles there